# DNS does not resolve locally

Tags: dns, windows-server-2012-r2

I have an issue with my DNS infrastructure :

I have a `company.com` publicly registered domain, which is just configured with a root A record and a wildcard CNAME to another domain (where we have our website and other public IPs)
However, internally, i have an AD DS set on internal.domain.com, configured with a public DNS forwarder.

When I do a nslookup of `a.internal.domain.com` on the internal DC (which is set as a A record), it resolve it as `a.internal.domain.com.domain.com` which is obviously not what i'm after (`b.domain.com` works and forward perfectly)

I've looked in the server configuration but i don'rt seem to find any issue there.

As far as I understand the DNS system, it should try to solve it itself in it's own forward zone before forwarding the request down the chain ?

I'm using the integrated DNS server on a windows server 2012 R2

Comment: Did you ever get this one worked out? If not, I can look over some settings here in a few for a similar setup and see what I have configured for records between domains like this in one environment I support.

Answer (score 0):

Domain names in DNS zone files append the full domain name of the zone itself for any names internal to the file.  So if you have a zone `example.com` and you have a record like this in in the file:

```
www IN A 10.0.0.1
```

The record name will end up really being for `www.example.com`.  This is a problem if you want to put in full names.  To get this to not happen, add a '.' to the end of the label:

```
www.example.com. IN A 10.0.0.1
```

So what you probably need in your file is `a.internal.domain.com.` (note the trailing '.')

Comment: this would be true if i used a bind or other linux based DNS. Sadly, here, I'm on a Windows server DNS, with no config file per se

Comment: It's still misconfigured in this fashion, and the zone-file format is actually standardized.  So if you have a GUI, still add a '.' to the end of your name in it.

Comment: I've double checked it and it's definitly not a misconfiguration like that. especially as i don't want to input full FQDN but PQDN.